# Enzyme is not finding component by props

Tags: reactjs, jsx, enzyme

I've got a component I'm testing with Enzyme that looks like the following:

```
<RichTextEditor name="name" onChange={[Function]} value="<p>what</p>" focus={false}>
  <div className="rich-text-editor">
  <div className="btn-group" role="group">
  <StyleButton active={false} icon="fa-list-ul" label="UL" onToggle={[Function]} style="unordered-list-item">
  // ...
```

I'm trying to detect the presence of the StyleButton component there like so:

```
mount(<RichTextEditor />).find('StyleButton[label="UL"]')
```

But no components are returned. I can find all the StyleButtons by just searching for the string "StyleButton" but I can't find by property, including just by using the property selector on its own.

The first code block I pasted up there is from the debug output of mounting the RichTextEditor, so the StyleButton is definitely there.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In the docs there is no option to mix **name of component** with **props**:

- CSS Selectors
- Component Constructors
- Component Display Name
- Object Property Selector

You can use [findWhere](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/findWhere.html):

```
 wrapper.findWhere(n => n.name() === 'StyleButton' && n.prop('label') === 'UL')
```

Comment: Oh man, you're right. I confused the tag + property css selector for component + property. I thought I saw similar in other source code but it wasn't quite that. Thanks.

Comment: you can combine `find` and `findWhere`:

`wrapper.find('StyleButton').findWhere(n => n.prop('label') === 'UL')`

Comment: Tried the above comment but didn't work like the answer does.

Answer (score 4):

Since `find` returns another `ReactWrapper` you could chain them that way:

`mount(<RichTextEditor />).find({label:"UL"}).find(StyleButton)`

Note: the order matters.

Inspired by @romanlv's comment, but I find this syntax clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Line of code to mount rich text editor!

```
mount(<RichTextEditor />).find('StyleButton').find('[label="UL"]');
```

Comment: You should also add an explanation with your example.