# Can't find element in jest even though wrapper.debug() shows it

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to access a `Dropdown` with `name=genes` property using `jest`:

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    const middlewares = [thunk]
    const store = configureStore(middlewares)(STATE1)
    wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store} >
        <SavedVariants match={INIT_MATCH_PROPS} {...stateProps} {...dispatchProps} />
      </Provider>
    )
    //console.log(wrapper.debug())
  })


it('selects genes in the genes dropdown', () => {
    const selector = `Dropdown[name='genes']`

    const genesDropdownBefore = wrapper.find(selector)
    console.log(genesDropdownBefore)
})
```

`console.log()` shows an empty object, so it can't find it. If I supply the class `Dropdown` (`semanti-ui-react`) it is not working either. When I do `wrapper.debug()` I see the dropdown, here is the excerpt:

```
...
    <Dropdown aria-describedby={{...}} aria-invalid={true} selection={true} fluid={true} 
meta={{...}} onChange={[Function]} name="genes" onBlur={{...}} onDragStart={[Function]} 
onDrop={[Function]} onFocus={[Function]} value="" placeholder="Select genes" 
renderLabel={[Function]} allowAdditions={false} multiple={true} onAddItem={[Function]} search={true} options={{...}} noResultsMessage={{...}} tabIndex="0" content={[undefined]} disabled={[undefined]} required={[undefined]} type={[undefined]} id={[undefined]} additionLabel="Add " additionPosition="top" closeOnBlur={true} closeOnEscape={true} deburr={false} icon="dropdown" minCharacters={1} openOnFocus={true} searchInput="text" selectOnBlur={true} selectOnNavigation={true} wrapSelection={true}>
                                                                          <Ref innerRef={{...}}>
                                                                            <RefFindNode innerRef={{...}}>
...
```

I looked into `html` when its rendered in `Chrome` and also tried selecting it like that:

```
const selector = `div[name='genes']`
const genesDropdownBefore = wrapper.find(selector)
```

No success. What else could I try?

> Update

Tried to use `id`:

```
const selector = '#geneSearchField'
const genesDropdownBefore = wrapper.find(selector)
console.log(genesDropdownBefore)
```

I verified using `wrapper.debug()` that the `Dropdown` has `id="geneSearchField"`. The selection was still empty. I also tried a different selector with no success:

```
wrapper.findWhere(n => n.name() === 'Dropdown' && n.prop('name') === 'genes')
```

that I found in this thread: [Enzyme is not finding component by props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776121/enzyme-is-not-finding-component-by-props)

Comment: What's wrapper? Is it the mounted component or shallowed one?

Comment: Its mounted, I updated the question

Comment: I should probably add that this Dropdown is rendered as a redux-form Field. I tried looking for it as Field, but its not successful either.

Comment: Can you try providing id attribute to this DropDown? It will be much more easier for you to find this element with id.

Comment: I updated the question in the 'update' section. Please, see. No luck basically with id either.

Comment: It literally can't find anything

Answer (score 0):

The issue was coming from the fact that I did not know how to correctly print out the found by `jest` html. Just logging like `console.log(genesDropdownBefore)` is printing an empty wrapper object which is very misleading. What I needed to do to move on is to print out it as `console.log(genesDropdownBefore.debug())`.

Comment: So now you find the cause of the issue?

Comment: Yes, it was selecting the elements, it was actually working but when I printed out the selection: `console.log(genesDropdownBefore)` it showed `ReactWrapper {}` which I interpreted as no selection. I am completely new to testing, so don't know many things.